# Using Database(SQLIte or others) in Cordova Application for android/IOS/Windows in VS2015

Tags: android, sqlite, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I am trying to make an android application using Cordova template in Visual Studio 2015. Since Cordova is for HTML,js and other plugins, how can we store data from the cordova android app in any database?
I found the compatibility of SQLite with cordova apps but not working.
Can any one suggest steps to integrate SQLite or other database in cordova VS2015?

Comment: There are a few options here, to help narrow the choices can you clarify what you're trying to do? Is your goal to just store local data for an application (e.g. store todo list items on the device) or are you trying to access data in a database hosted on a server (e.g. store todo list items in a cloud-based database)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jordan. My main concern is to save and retrieve data using cordova app from any database.What would be suitable for middle and large scale mobile application? Is it storing data locally for an application or using hosted database server? If it's locally or using server then what and how to use? Kindly suggest...

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you wouldn’t connect directly to a SQL Server Database directly from a mobile device. Instead, you’d access REST APIs via a web service. If you have data stored locally on the device, you can use either Web SQL or Indexed DB. Most developers recommend against Web SQL since the standard has been deprecated. Indexed DB, therefore, is the recommended path. I personally recommend using this Cordova plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-indexeddb